# Azure Data Studio - cannot find backup option

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-studio

I need to backup a database I've got access to, but cannot find the option.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/tutorial-backup-restore-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 I can simply right-click the database, go to Manage, and it should be there.

I can right-click on the database and get a "Manage" option, but that just gives me some info:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Azure Data Studio database backup functionality is for on-prem or IaaS SQL Server databases. For Azure SQL Database, create a bacpac export instead. This can be done from within ADS by installing the [SQL Server Dacpac extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/sql-server-dacpac-extension?view=sql-server-ver15) for ADS.

[image: Data-tier Application Wizard export option]

Comment: Yep, that seems to have done the job thanks!